# Get the number of integers between each given range

Tags: python, arrays, range, binary-search

The task:

> Write a function that receives 3 arrays and returns an array.  The
> first array contains n integers, their values range between 0 and
> 10^9. "numbers". The second array is a low-range array, which contains
> the lower end of a range, it contains q integers. "low". The third
> array is a high-range array, which contains the higher end of a range,
> it contains q integers. "high".
>
> The function should return an array that contains the number of
> integers in the first array, that fall in its range, given by the
> low-range and high-range arrays.
>
> In the returned array, at index i, there should be the number of
> integers in "numbers" which are bigger or equal to low[i] and smaller or equal to high[i].

Examples:
count_range([12,13,14,15,17],[14],[14]) should return [1] 
count_range([12,13,14,15,17],[14,15],[14,18]) should return [1,2] 
count_range([12,13,14,15,17],[12],[17]) should return [5]

This is how I solved the question but I feel like there might be a more efficient way to solve seeing as the arrays could be long and the numbers could be really big.

I'd be glad to get some insights or tests that challenge this could to help me think in a better direction.

```
def binarySearch(data, val):
    highIndex = len(data) - 1
    lowIndex = 0
    while highIndex > lowIndex:
        index = math.ceil((highIndex + lowIndex) / 2)
        sub = data[index]
        if sub > val:
            if highIndex == index:
                return sorted([highIndex, lowIndex])
            highIndex = index
        else:
            if lowIndex == index:
                return sorted([highIndex, lowIndex])
            lowIndex = index
    return sorted([highIndex, lowIndex])


def count_range(numbers, low, high):
    numbers.sort()
    result = []
    range_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i] not in range_dict:
            range_dict[numbers[i]] = i
    for i in range(len(low)):
        low_r = low[i]
        high_r = high[i]
        if low_r not in range_dict:
            range_dict[low_r] = binarySearch(numbers, low_r)[0]
        low_index = range_dict.get(low_r)
        if high_r not in range_dict:
            range_dict[high_r] = binarySearch(numbers, high_r)[0]
        high_index = range_dict.get(high_r)
        while high_index+1 < len(numbers) and numbers[high_index + 1] == numbers[high_index]:
            high_index += 1
        if low_r in numbers or low_r < numbers[0]:
            low_index -= 1
        result.append(high_index - low_index)
    print(result)
    return result
```

Comment: What are you asking for help in? is something broken or are you trying to ask how it could be optimized / made more pythonic?

Comment: `zip(low,high)` would alleviate you having to use indexing to retreive the values. [https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: If you don't have to write your own search, use Python's - [https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect)

Comment: @AndrewRyan it's wrong and wouldn't run on a longer list of 10^9 elements.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'll edit and add some examples, but the example you gave is correct because I forgot to mention that the counter should include the edges, which means between 42 and 42 there is one number which is 42 and it exists on the first array

Comment: What should `count_range([7,7,7], [6], [8]), count_range([7,7,7], [7], [8]), count_range([7,7,7], [6], [7]), count_range([7,7,7], [7], [7])` compute? You compute `[3], [1], [3], [1]`.

Comment: Are the ranges guaranteed to be valid, i.e., is the "lower end" always *lower* than the "higher end"?

Comment: @KellyBundy I edited the post, to be clear out that the edges are included. Yes the ranges are guaranteed to be valid.

Comment: @KellyBundy for your question above, about the 4 similar examples, it should return [3] for all of them, I'm glad you're opening my eyes to a lot of notes, I'll fix these problems and update the code.

Comment: What are the limits for how many numbers and queries there might be?

Comment: @KellyBundy 10^9 if I remember correctly :)

Comment: That seems rather unlikely. Are you sure you're not confusing that with the size of the number range? Btw your code change made it much slower, in my benchmark its times increased from ~70 ms to ~2200 ms.

Comment: Please don't invalidate answers.

Comment: @KellyBundy This is my first question on StackOverflow so please forgive my mistakes :)
I noticed that the change I made increased the time but it also solved the problem which we discussed earlier about the 4 similar examples, if you have any suggestions as to how I can solve it and keep the times ~70 ms I would be grateful. I still need to read and understand the bisect functions before trying to re-write them.

Comment: @KellyBundy please don't keep editing my question, this was required in the task, I forgot to mention it beforehand. This is an interview question so it can't use external packages. And that's the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Please don't keep invalidating answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python's `bisect`:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

def count_range(numbers, low, high):
    numbers.sort()
    return [bisect_right(numbers, hi) - bisect_left(numbers, lo)
            for hi, lo in zip(high, low)]
```

In my solution, the sorting actually took about 90% of my time, then handling the queries only took about 10% of my time.

Benchmark with 100,000 numbers and 1000 ranges ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRLb5wwEL7zK3yJYm8IXRL1tcpG6qGqqko5NEeEkBdMsMpLxjRNq/72rcc22ISu1EjlAnjm@@abh6d/klXXXr/rxfHIm74TEjVUVkFQsBIdeEvF0z2jIq9wQSUN0Xdak12A1FPxh@pzW7AfaI9q1mo7QZco1ta6e5yMW33wWPGaeaDb2cXQwcMtAhREOeM1xg5wMQMIeoWuyIwaxoPCQPhEE6SOr9TGW1DtoliLp39vIi9d4BFMjqJFgyoLK3AyQ8JZS0oWIL8omnO2snpgKw2uSv9Pgld5p@CfWHTP825sZSZo@8CyeyoobsfmwMSgPUOdoB0Aa4iAFBMbZhhrqSInpgmGpuA5nP36rc/KTiCupBkjhtGxTIS49B0ysdaEpynkdIpEyfMJ1G8mYDS7R4UM/Abpc/jwDaYbytR2cibWApY98YRpf9C0uCd@vTJBkm260DTNuOOJHpjExjl4Np8vkmMAp/UY@0KQPjqhyLq7jujeRrTvWVtgD3np5XWBYuIPnAGtJ@sLq@unF46WJkwOfGC5olHO0s8NVo@11ayUPvfyfsDoVBzOoa4/ea9z0RpIulZ6x9v47Wmlk6xhbHDsxtL666m64TcV0aZaQaegjkgFLUXXIMkbxlWzzRY2f4H9U1qKrjF@JsvJz8s5RH5xTCqSDTKD3Yit4K8f7j59nLqN4@1m8574NTcmFSzKq47nbMAaEaJve3B@TdzFBl9sV4rFDLTpazZBrgh5ts@gCpm7t/F2u7U@yUZVJA3VG4oCUwxV2phAixFY98KkqiZTzVQ5tvmyN3AyNTDZpRqn33oF7GDxgQtk83z5heuhDdfTEQRrSYrMK30AeUMQSF0HMwp7wVuJPeHJLt4qZfAdZVlLG5ZloG9ZtuvlNTkddir5X0LDA1vZzBmuaXMo6M4vYmj597HrohF8fvYmikvUDOgcnSEs0QbF7JqsdDsEOR7/AA)):

```
  71.6 ms  count_range_Sara
  24.1 ms  count_range_Kelly
6303.6 ms  count_range_Nin17

  70.5 ms  count_range_Sara
  23.1 ms  count_range_Kelly
6225.0 ms  count_range_Nin17

  64.5 ms  count_range_Sara
  23.1 ms  count_range_Kelly
6306.7 ms  count_range_Nin17
```

(Note: Sara's solution I measured is the original slightly buggy one, which I included despite the buggyness as the question is about efficiency. And Nin17's solution that I measured is their original one from their now deleted answer, not the NumPy one.)

Comment: That is an amazing solution, thank you for that!
How would you solve it without importing any packages or libraries, you could only use math if you need to, I'd like to see a solution like that to prepare for job interview questions.

Comment: @SaraKhatib Pretty much the same way, except I'd write the bisect functions myself. Or maybe just write one and use it for both ends (by adding or subtracting 1 from one of the ends). Your binary search function seems a bit complicated and unconventional. You can see Python's by clicking on the source code link at the top of [bisect's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html).

Answer (score 0):

With numpy:

```
import numpy as np
def count_range(numbers, low, high):
    numbers.sort()
    return np.searchsorted(numbers, high, 'right') - np.searchsorted(numbers, low, 'left')
```

Benchmark:

```
from timeit import timeit
def test_data():
    RANGE = range(10**9)
    numbers = random.choices(RANGE, k=10**5)
    ranges = (sorted(random.sample(RANGE, 2))
              for _ in range(1000))
    [*low], [*high] = zip(*ranges)
    return [numbers, low, high]
test = test_data()
%timeit kelly(*[t.copy() for t in test])
test2 = [np.array(i) for i in test]
%timeit Nin17(*[t.copy() for t in test2])
```

Output:

```
13.4 ms ± 77.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.63 ms ± 14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: changed it, numpy is still faster

Comment: The list isn't sorted for the second application anyway

Comment: ```kelly(*test)
print(test == sorted(test))
Nin17(*test)
(kelly(*test) == Nin17(*test)).all()``` output: ```False
True```

Comment: using your terminology... ‍♂️I've edited the answer to use your testing code exactly

Comment: but mine is still faster than when yours is first

Comment: when the functions are in the equivalent positions in funcs, Nin17 is always faster

Comment: this is why I use ```%timeit``` as you don't need to worry about any of this and you get the same times as calling ```deepcopy``` where you used ```[:]``` and you don't time the copying

Comment: ok explain this then: ```import timeit
import time
def test(lst):
    print(lst)
    lst.sort()
    print(lst)
    time.sleep(5)
lst = [1,2,3,4,3]
%timeit test(lst[:])``` output: ```[1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4]...``` gives the same result in my timeit if I change it to ```test[:]``` as with ```test``` (for the tests above)

Comment: yes but with ```%timeit test(lst[:])``` they aren't and both give the same times when testing the actual functions

Comment: numbers is a list of ints?

Comment: so now the numpy function is showing as being comparatively even faster than before

Comment: numpy is still faster

Comment: Yes, as expected. And now it's finally demonstrated properly :-)

Comment: well tbf it's been demonstrated for ages

Comment: You mean in general, not by you here previously? Yes, that's why I'm saying "as expected".

Comment: well both as who cares about timing the sorting and even now its not timing like for like as it takes longer to create the copies of the numpy arrays

Comment: Not both. Your previous attempts were all flawed. The sorting is part of the solution, so it needs to be cared about. How long do the copies take? I don't believe that it takes longer for the NumPy arrays.

Comment: well not accounting for it doesn't change the ratio of the times  ‍♂️```a = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
b = [np.array(i) for i in a]
%timeit [i.copy() for i in a]
%timeit [i.copy() for i in b]``` gives ```313 ns ± 0.364 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
975 ns ± 3.49 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)```

Comment: Those are tiny. That has nothing to do with the large data. Try it with the large data.

Comment: ```a = [list(range(100000000)), list(range(1000)), list(range(1000))]
b = [np.array(i) for i in a]
%timeit [i.copy() for i in a]
%timeit [i.copy() for i in b]``` gives ```414 ms ± 6.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
204 ms ± 1.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)``` either way, not the same and with the ```test_data()``` gives ```217 µs ± 5.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
26.6 µs ± 139 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)```

Comment: That's more like it, although I don't see why you keep making up different data. Anyway, 204 ms isn't longer than 414 ms. For the actual test's data, copying the NumPy arrays is about 4.2 times faster for me than copying the Python lists, and for the NumPy solution it's only about 1.4% of the total time whereas for the Python solution it's about 1.8% of the total time. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1WyE.png).

Comment: And 26.6 us isn't longer than 217 us, either :-)

Comment: Why not it proves my point that it's still not timing the same thing

Comment: What do you mean? What's different?

Comment: One is faster than the other?

Comment: Yes. And your point is?

Comment: Therefore it's not timing the same thing

Comment: What different things, exactly?

Comment: One is timing copy some python lists and run some python and the other is timing copy some numpy arrays and run some numpy functions

Comment: Is there a problem with that? I mean, you make it sound like there's still something bad here. And I don't think so.

Comment: Well for the same reason that using sorted arguments 'needs to be cared about' as it's part of the solution, this isn't part of the solution and so shouldn't be timed

Comment: That's true, but that's a completely different magnitude. Like I said in my answer, the sorting took 90% of my time. That's not negligible. But the 1.8% for the copying is.

Comment: Yeah but it takes ~90% of the time for both of them so you can just ignore it

Comment: **If** it takes about the same percentage for both, then it's irrelevant for their **relative** times (ratio), yes. But it hasn't been shown to be about the same for both, and it would still be bad to show *absolute* times excluding a part that takes 90%.

Comment: Well it has because those were the times I had 4 hours ago and not really because the times are dependent on what system you've run them on anyway so the absolute time doesn't really mean alot

Comment: What times? ...

Comment: 1.38 ms ± 44.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
643 µs ± 25.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: Those times show what?

Comment: with sorted input